# Firestore filtering by document reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to filter by document reference in React Native. I'm using `react-native-firebase`. I want all documents whose field (DocumentReference) is in the provided array:

```
 const subscriber = firestore()
        .collection('strategyCounts')
        .where(
          'strategy',
          'in',
          user.strategies.map(strategy => {
            return strategy.path;
          }),
        ).onSnapshot(...)
```

`user.strategies` looks like this `["/strategies/id", "/strategy/id2"]`

[image: strategyCounts]

[image: strategies]

[image: users]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter by document reference, you need to pass `DocumentReference` objects in the array. So something like:

```
  user.strategies.map(strategy => {
    return firestore().doc(strategy.path);
  }),
```

Or (slightly shorter):

```
  user.strategies.map(strategy => firestore().doc(strategy.path)),
```

Comment: Yes, but nothing gets returned. I added a few photos

Comment: Ooh, I had an another where. Works :)